# Blazor page elements other than Body

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app, trying to understand the structure. Inside the MainLayout.razor page, I see the tag @Body, and this is where each page's content is rendered.

I am wondering, is it possible to add additional render element to the mainLayout page? For example, a @Header section. And I would prefer to define this section inside each individual page as well.

In other words, for each page, besides the main content, it also needs to define Header, Footer, or whatever render element I define in the MainLayout. This way, I can have customize Header/Footer elements that are unique for each page.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know if in your layout page you can detect the navigations events: https://blazor-university.com/routing/detecting-navigation-events/ and change the layout to meet your requeriments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MainLayout.razor`

**Note:** The use of a method to update the render fragment fields I deliberately made private which then calls `StateHasChanged()`. Other methods could easily be created to clear or set other fields.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="top-row px-4">
                @header
            </div>

            <div class="content px-4">
                @Body
                @footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private RenderFragment header;
    private RenderFragment footer;

    public void SetHeaderAndFooter(RenderFragment header, RenderFragment footer)
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.footer = footer;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

`LayoutSetter.cs`

```
public class LayoutSetter : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Header { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Layout.SetHeaderAndFooter(Header, Footer);
    }
}
```

On any page...

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<LayoutSetter>
    <Header>
        Hello
    </Header>
    <Footer>
        Goodbye
    </Footer>
</LayoutSetter>
```

Comment: Looks nice. Is it fully null proof?

Comment: @HenkHolterman https://github.com/BrianLParker/LayoutDemo

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian, I will give it a shot.

Comment: I did something similar in this library, I wasn't smart enough to use Render Fragments then :) https://www.nuget.org/packages/CleanView/

Comment: I've implemented your code Brian, works likes a charm, thanks again.

Comment: @ Brian Parker, I've  implemented your code, and it works perfectly well. But the issue with this solution is that the header and footer appear for all the pages, not only for the Index page...

Comment: @enet  Yes its a setter. It just sets the value. He did say he was going to set it on each page "And I would prefer to define this section inside each individual page"

Comment: thanks for this. does anybody know a good way to re render the layout section if the content changes? For example if i have an integer bound to a value in the content and inside the render fragment and change the value it does not change in the layout but does in the child content

Comment: Excellent proof of concept to create more complex scenarios.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

#### Here is a more Dynamic solution:

`MainLayout.razor`

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <AppNavigation />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <AppHeader />
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-row px-4">
        <AppFooter />
    </div>
</div>
```

`AppHeader.razor`

```
@implements IDisposable

@LayoutService.Header
@code {
    [Inject]
    public ILayoutService LayoutService { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LayoutService.PropertyChanged += LayoutService_PropertyChanged;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void LayoutService_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ILayoutService.Header))
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (LayoutService != null)
        {
            LayoutService.PropertyChanged -= LayoutService_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

}
```

`ILayoutService.cs`

```
public interface ILayoutService
{    
    RenderFragment Header { get; }    
    SetHeader HeaderSetter { get; set; }
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
    void UpdateHeader();
}
```

`LayoutService.cs`

```
public class LayoutService : ILayoutService, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public RenderFragment Header => HeaderSetter?.ChildContent;

    public SetHeader HeaderSetter
    {
        get => headerSetter;
        set
        {
            if (headerSetter == value) return;
            headerSetter = value;
            UpdateHeader();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateHeader() => NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Header));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private SetHeader headerSetter;
}
```

#### The Setter

`SetHeader.cs`

```
public class SetHeader : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    private ILayoutService Layout { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Layout != null)
        {
            Layout.HeaderSetter = this;
        }
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        var shouldRender = base.ShouldRender();
        if (shouldRender)
        {
            Layout.UpdateHeader();
        }
        return shouldRender;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Layout != null)
        {
            Layout.HeaderSetter = null;
        }
    }

}
```

#### Provide the service:

In my case `Program.cs`

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<ILayoutService, LayoutService>();
```

#### Example

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<SetHeader>
    <p>Hello Current count: @currentCount</p>
</SetHeader>

<SetFooter>
    <p>Goodbye Current count: @currentCount</p>
</SetFooter>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount() => currentCount++;
}
```

[image]

This also clears the values on navigation as I am using `IDisposable` . The Setter does not have to be set (Null is ok). If more than one setter is used the latest takes precedence. I have not tested dynamically removing multiple setters on one page.

Here is a [repo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/DynamicLayout) using WebAssembly 3.2.1