# How to get reference to the Blazor MainLayout from a child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I put some global Blazor Components in the MainLayout of my Blazor Server side app. They are used to show Alert, Confirmation, Warning, ...

From a child component, how can I get the reference to the MainLayout in order to call my global Alert, Confirmation functions?

The child component is dynamic and may be in any nested level. So we don't know how many level from it to the root MainLayout.

It is like the concept of ApplicationContext.MainForm in Winform app.

Comment: I answered a very similar question that applies here as well. It demonstrates how to pass a render fragment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255443/blazor-page-elements-other-than-body/64260515#64260515

Comment: This is very smart way to manipulate RenderFragment. Thanks @BrianParker, I definitely will give it  a try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cascade a reference to the MainLayout component to its children and thier descendants by using the CascadingValue component as demonstrated below:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<CascadingValue Value="this">
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>

</CascadingValue>
```

And in the child components you should define a CascadingParameter property that receive the reference as the following:

```
 [CascadingParameter]
 public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }
```

Now you can do something interesting from the child component.

Comment: This solution is simple and answer directly to the question. It just works. Thank you @enet

Comment: Passing the layout as cascading value hides a big problem (at least in dotnet6 Blazor Server) - every time you navigate (go to a new page) the current component/page "OnParametersSet" method is being called. For example, if you're on page "A" and navigate to page "B" you'll get a call to "OnParametersSet" on "A" before you get any events on "B".

Answer (score 8):

What about using a registered service(singleton or scoped). This service implements an event that is thrown when a child component wants to display the alert. The MainLayout listens to the event of the alert service and if a new event is thrown then the MainLayout shows the alert.

The service could look like following:

```
 public class AlertService
{
    public event EventHandler<AlertEventArgs> AlertMessageChanged;

    protected virtual void OnAlertMessageChanged(AlertEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<AlertEventArgs> handler = AlertMessageChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void SetAlertMessage(string alertMessage)
    {
        var eventArgs = new AlertEventArgs();
        eventArgs.AlertMessage = alertMessage;
       OnAlertMessageChanged(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

In the AlertEventArgs there could be a property "**AlertMessage**" or something like that.
And in the MainLayout you register an event handler for the ***OnAlertMessageChanged*** event

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject AlertService alertService   

<div class="main">
   ...
</div>

@code { 

    override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        alertService.AlertMessageChanged += HandleAlertMessageChanged;
    }

    private void HandleAlertMessageChanged(AlertEventArgs args)
    {
        //Show the alert
    }
}
```

For confirmations or warnings, you can extend the existing service or you create new ones and of course, you need to register the services.

Comment: This is elegant way to get the functionality which I'm searching for. Actually I followed your suggestion to implement my system.  However, I marked the answer of enet  because it directly addressed the question.  Thank you @troYman

Comment: @troYman. Thanks for that answer, but iam facing a problem with this. The AlertMassageChanged is always null.  I copied for testing exactly your code and created the service and injected it in the MainLayout. VS was critized the HandleAlertMessageChanged method and i corrected it to "private void HandleAlertMessageChanged(object? sender, AlertEventArgs e)". Any suggustions? Thanks in advance

Comment: @sentenz : Did you register the services as a singleton or as a transient service?

Comment: yep that was the problem :D found it 10min after that post :/

Comment: HandleAlertMessageChanged(AlertEventArgs args) is correct? or HandleAlertMessageChanged(Object obj, AlertEventArgs args)?