# template a blazor RenderFragment to a layout from a page or component

Tags: layout, rendering, blazor

I want to have customizable content in my layout page in blazor. I tried adding a `RenderFragment` parameter to the layout and adding makeup with the same name in my component but it is not rendered in my layout.

`layout.razor`

```
<header>
    @HeaderContent
</header>

@body

@code
{
    [Parameter] 
    public RenderFragment HeaderContent { get; set; }
}
```

`component.razor`

```
<HeaderContent>
    <p>my page specific content</p>
</HeaderContnt>
```

But the `HeaderContent` is rendered in the body. Can anybody explain how to do this? Or why it's not possible in a layout? The only way I have found that works is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255443/blazor-page-elements-other-than-body/64260515#64260515) but it won't refresh the content if I change a bound parameter inside the `RenderFragment.

Comment: You cannot update properties. You have to call a function like I have to set the fragments then call state has changed. In fact updating the properties directly should have given your a warning my ide does.

Comment: hi thanks for the help. yes the pseudo code above doesn't work. I was hoping to find a way triggering the header to re render when the content is changed inside the layout setter. at the moment the rendered content is static in the layout so if i change a property it only updates the content and not the layout

Comment: I added another solution to that page. A bit more complicated but I am happy with the result.

Answer (score 7):

- Flexible Content
- Clears on Navigation
- Updates without any wiring up

`MainLayout.razor.cs`

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

...
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        @headerContent
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        <CascadingValue Value="this">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>
    </div>
...
@code {
    RenderFragment headerContent => setHeader?.ChildContent;
    SetHeader setHeader;

    public void SetHeader(SetHeader setHeader)
    {
        this.setHeader = setHeader;
        Update();
    }

    public void Update() => StateHasChanged();
}
```

#### Setter

```
public class SetHeader : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout MainLayout { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MainLayout.SetHeader(this);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        var shouldRender = base.ShouldRender();
        if (shouldRender)
        {
            MainLayout.Update();
        }
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MainLayout?.SetHeader(null);
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
<SetHeader>
    <p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
</SetHeader>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was pretty close but it didn't work for me.
that's how i do fix it:

***MainLayout:***

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        @headerContent
        @*<a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>*@
    </div>
    <div class="content px-4">
        <CascadingValue Value="this">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>
    </div>
</div>
@code {
    RenderFragment headerContent => setHeader?.ChildContent;
    SetHeader setHeader;

    public void SetHeader(SetHeader setHeader)
    {
        if (setHeader == null) return;

        this.setHeader = setHeader;
        this.setHeader.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

***SetHeader:***

```
public class SetHeader : ComponentBase, IDisposable
    {
        [CascadingParameter] public MainLayout MainLayout { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
        
        public event Action OnChange;
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            MainLayout.SetHeader(this);
            Update();
            base.OnInitialized();
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            OnChange?.Invoke();
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            MainLayout?.SetHeader(null);
        }

    }
```

***Usage into any razor page:***

```
<SetHeader @ref="@setHeader">
    <p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

</SetHeader>
```

***Into the code of that page:***

```
SetHeader setHeader;

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        setHeader.Update();
    }
```

Now only one problem remains... when you change page you have to put in that page an empty  in order to clear it

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Brian Parker worked perfectly for me. However, I wanted two headers fragments, so I could not use the default ChildContent naming.

***MainLayout:***

```
  <div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        @FirstHeader
      
    </div>
   <div class="top-row px-4">
        @SecondHeader
       
    </div>
    <div class="content px-4">
        <CascadingValue Value="this">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>
    </div>
</div>
@code 
{
   RenderFragment FirstHeader => _setHeader?.FirstHeaderTemplate;
   RenderFragment SecondHeader => _setHeader?.SecondHeaderTemplate;

   SetHeader _setHeader;

   public void SetHeader(SetHeader setHeader)
   {
       _setHeader = setHeader;
       Update();
   }

   public void Update() => StateHasChanged();
}
```

***SetHeader class:***

```
public class SetHeader : ComponentBase, IDisposable
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        public MainLayout MainLayout { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment FirstHeaderTemplate { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment SecondHeaderTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            MainLayout.SetHeader(this);
            base.OnInitialized();
        }

        protected override bool ShouldRender()
        {
            var shouldRender = base.ShouldRender();
            if (shouldRender)
            {
                MainLayout.Update();
            }
            return base.ShouldRender();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            MainLayout?.SetHeader(null);
        }
    }
```

***Usage:***

```
<SetHeader>
    <FirstHeaderTemplate>
         <LoginDisplay />
    </FirstHeaderTemplate>
    <SecondHeaderTemplate>
        <p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
    </SecondHeaderTemplate>
</SetHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

### .NET 7 Blazor Server Solution

None, and I mean absolutely none of the solutions across any of the posts regarding this topic had worked for me in .NET 7. I needed a way for the Layout to update its header whenever `<TitleHeader>` or `<ActionsHeader>` were modified by the Page. I kept running into infinite rendering loops when another custom component was referenced within the `ChildContent` of the header part.

After some extensive searching, I found this solution from GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28182#issuecomment-1378804578. It works as expected without relying on any services or event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8 Blazor now supports this with [sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0). There are a couple of different naming/referencing methods but I prefer the `SectionID`:

1. add the `using` statement for the sections into the `_Imports.razor` or top of your layout file:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Sections
```

2. add a static object to your layout's `@code` block:

```
@code {
    internal static object MySection = new();
}
```

3. In your layout component, add a `SectionOutlet` which matches the name of the static object:

```
<SectionOutlet SectionId="MySection" />
```

4. In any component that uses this layout, add a `SectionContent` element whose `SectionId` matches the layout name and static object:

```
<SectionContent SectionId="MainLayout.MySection">
    <span>Hi!</span>
</SectionContent>
```